# Better way to display items in list view after translating them from card view

Tags: lists, mobile-application, card-views

I am having difficulty translating the following card view into a list view:

[image]

This is what I've accomplished so far:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can make it more workable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, this is iOS right?

Quite simply, take the existing cards, and put them in a UICollectionView with "bouncy" physics.

(So, you know - it's just like a table view, but each one sort of "pushes" the other along .. the small gap between each panel/card, is as if on a little spring.)

That's pretty much the standard metaphor now to present "many cards" right?  Does it help??

---

In short - I can see nothing at all wrong with what you've done.  (BTW I assume that the "half card" seen at the bottom, the BBC story, is simply shown that way because the whole list is scrolling, and that one happens to be cutoff currently.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. it's not iOS, I am currently just mocking up the UI in Axure RP

Comment: sure - ok, then it's just "any sort of list" of those cards.  Exactly like - say - when you use whatsapp (or any feed) picture the "speech bubbles" which you see on the screen, in a scroll, if you're looking at one chat.  That's all there is to it, surely?  (Just as you've done.)